# Can Ogier channel?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

Is there any mention in the wheel of time series or other related works that mention Ogier channeling, or with the ability to channel? They obviously needed some help with the power in order to grow the way gates, but were there any in their society that could channel?

Comment: Even if they can, they live in steddings, so they probably never do.

Comment: ogier are questionable to even be from the planet, they may be from another dimension or world.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Word of God answer from an interview I found [here](http://www.dragonmount.com/forums/topic/64874-loial-and-the-ogier/):

> Wotmania/Dragonmount Q&A - 9 December 2002
>
> Q: Why can't Ogier channel the One Power?
>
> RJ: Why can't fish sing? Why can't sparrows do the tango? Why can't I figure my own income tax? I'd really like to know the answer to that last one!

So no, they can't. Even if they could (see my comment above) they wouldn't be able to, since they live in steddings and basically never leave.

Comment: That makes sense

Comment: It wouldn't make sense for the Ogier to be able to channel, since they get sick if they live outside the stedding for too long

Comment: @Harlemme but that doesn't necessarily mean they couldn't channel on its own.  That would be more of a reason why they wouldn't know they can channel.